# Problema con crear un backup en aws

Tags: sql-server, aws

Saludos tengo un problema con crear un backup  de una base sql server en un bucket de amazon web service 
me sale el siguiente error :

> Task execution has started.  Aborted the task because of a task
>   failure or an overlap with your preferred backup window for RDS
>   automated backup.  Task has been aborted [2020-03-27 16:58:22.083]
>   Access Denied.

Esto me acurre cuando ejecuto

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database
    @source_db_name='TopQuality', 
    @s3_arn_to_backup_to='arn:aws:s3:::sqlrdsadmin0231/backup1.bak',
    @overwrite_s3_backup_file=1
```

Por favor si alguien me puede dar una guía de que hacer , y cambien el json del iam , pero no se que mas se puede hacer.

Comment: Access Denied... ¿Tienes privilegios IAM para poder ejecutar el backup? ¿Y para acceder al bucket de s3?

Answer (score 0):

Resolví mi problema cambiando los permisos en IAM lo remplace por esto

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::nombrebucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::nombrebucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```